# python - Is there any ways to reshape data from html?

Tags: python, html, selenium, beautifulsoup

Hello i'm trying to collect result data from the baccarat site. Here's the image of the data I want to collect (circled)

[image]

code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='C:/chromedriver/chromedriver.exe')
driver.get('https://ggl-maxim.com/')

driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="body"]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/fieldset/input[1]').send_keys('tnrud3080')
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="body"]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/fieldset/input[2]').send_keys('tnrud3080')
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="body"]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/fieldset/button[1]').click()

time.sleep(2)
driver.get('https://ggl-maxim.com/api/popup/popup_menu.asp?mobile=0&lobby=EVOLUTION')
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it("gameIframe"))
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".svg--1nrnH")))

targets = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".svg--1nrnH")
res = []
for el in targets:
    res.append(el.get_attribute('innerHTML'))

print(*res, sep='\n')
```

well, I've succeed to get data from the website. However, I don't know how to reshape these data into list. For example, from the game table one let's assume the result is

red blue red blue red blue red

And my hopeful output would be :

```
[red, red, red, blue, blue, red, blue]
```

I need these kind of list for each baccarat tables. I need some help. Please help me!